# Equivalent -rdynamic flag in xlc compiler

Tags: aix, dynamic-loading, xlc

Is there an equivalent to the -rdynamic flag (gcc) into xlc compiler in AIX?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use option `-Wl,-bexpall` or you can create an _export file._